# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting this error when I am trying to delete a record from the database.   Here is the error in full

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: itp231.dba.nyp.com.bloommain, PID: 12274
                                                                              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM events WHERE id= ;
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                  at itp231.dba.nyp.com.bloommain.EventInformationPage$1.onClick(EventInformationPage.java:135)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Looking at the log, it directed me to this line of codes (my deleteRecord() method -

```
private void deleteRecord() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this person?");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

                    String sql = "DELETE FROM events WHERE id= " + id + ";";
                    db.execSQL(sql);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL,null);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Read your stack trace. The `String id` is empty, which would mean that the `EditText` is empty, or just has whitespace.

Comment: what is the type of id in database and also when you are passing value

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it could also be a problem with the Instant Run functionality if you are using Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1** - Your id is a blank string, therefore it can't be parsed in your SQL command.
**2** - If your id field is a TEXT (???), then you need to enclose it in single quotes.
**3** - For SQL commands, use `execSQL()` instead of `rawQuery()` - `rawQuery()` only works on... queries (`SELECT`)
**4** - And... prepared statements (or bound parameters) are a better choice. The placeholders (`?`) will be replaced automatically in their positional order and the quotes won't be a problem anymore (Android will handle that for you!).

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you, dear!

Comment: In addition to this-  NEVER WRITE SQL CODE THIS WAY.  You're WIDE open to an SQL injection attack.  *ALWAYS* use bind variables.  Writing queries with concatenated parameters is a horrible, horrible mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prepared statements`

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("DELETE FROM events WHERE id = ?");
stmt.bindString(1, id);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Has nobody hear heard of SQL injection and realize why this code is completely flawed?  If you haven't  go out and study.  If you have, then why aren't you teaching him the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 db.delete("events","id=?",new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

in which,

```
first paramater -> will be table name from where the deletion of data need to de done.
Second parameter -> Selection field in table.based on which field we are going to perform the deletion
Third parameter -> specifies the value,to be compare it with second paramters field if it is matched,then the particular column will be deleted.
```